# Why does matrix multiplication in NumPy not call the __add__ method?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

How does the method `__mul__` in the class `matrix` in NumPy work?
I want to implement a binary matrix multiplication, and I have a class `Binary`:

```
class Binary(int):
    def __init__(self, val):
        if val != 0:
            self.val = 1
        else:
            self.val = 0

    def __add__(self, other):
        print('add')
        return self.val ^ other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        print('radd')
        return self.val ^ other
```

My test:

```
from Binary import Binary
from numpy import matrix

i = Binary(1)
o = Binary(0)
a = matrix([i, i, o, i, i, o, o], dtype=Binary)
b = matrix([[o, o, i],
           [o, i, o],
           [o, i, i],
           [i, o, o],
           [i, o, i],
           [i, i, o],
           [i, i, i]], dtype=Binary)
print(a * b)
```

Result:

```
./test.py
[[2 1 2]]
```

The method `__add__` is not used. Whereas there is a summation in matrix multiplication.

Comment: You could use `dtype=np.bool_` to define a binary matrix natively instead of creating your own binary class

Comment: 9 years, wow 

Comment: :D there used to be an answer, you'd even accepted it, but it was a link-only answer so was deleted